# How do I offset orientation coordinates (Euler or Quaternion) by a 'calibration' orientation?

Tags: python, orientation, quaternions

I have a device called the Myo Armband and am using the orientation data it's outputting to control the position of an 'arm' in python (using Vizard for the rendering). Right now, I have it where I can do

```
arm.setQuat(armbandQuat)
```

and it kinda works. Up and down are accurate, but rotation about the vertical axis starts in a random direction each time. To fix this, I made it so that when you press the spacebar it records the offset quaternion. What I want to happen is that whenever you press space, the arm onscreen goes to a set '0' position and all motion about the vertical axis will be relative to that. In other words, the user will press space with their arm horizontal to calibrate it.

What do I need to do with these two quaternions to setQuat to the correctly rotated coordinates? Originally I thought you could just multiply the two quaternions together (or the inverse of the second), but if one is 0,0,0,0 then the arm will be frozen at 0,0,0,0.

I can also get and set Euler coordinates instead, if that's easier. It seems like quaternions are more of a perfect system for rotations like this though.

I think it should be somewhat simple, but I've spent hours looking up the answer and trying things out and nothing works.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Myo Armband, is there any way to calibrate the armband itself? Does it use accelerometers?

Comment: I don't believe that it does support calibration like that. It uses a gyroscope and accelerometers, so everything is pretty relative. I'm pretty sure there should be some sort of mathematical method to 'subtract' one rotation from the other, but I'm just confused about how to do that with quaternions where a rotation is done with multiplication.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820828/how-to-obtain-relative-rotation

Comment: Measuring the quaternion relative to "zero" is what it does anyways right? It wouldn't make sense to try to multiply it by 0,0,0,0. Do you have some other global coordinate system different from the armband? Also, if you convert to yaw-pitch-roll you might be able to just subtract the offset if the rotation about the vertical axis is the last rotation in the sequence.

Comment: The last suggestion you made is really obvious in hindsight and it worked! I had tried it before without it working, but I realize now that the roll of the armband will mess up the entire calibration. All I had to do was subtract the yaws and make sure that the Myo logo is facing upwards when hitting the spacebar to calibrate! Thank you!

Comment: @willpower2727 Why not put the solution from your comments into an answer so it can be accepted? You will get the reputations points then.....